# Python Multi-threading Race Condition behavior changes as a function of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, python-multithreading, race-condition

I was reading about race conditions in Python Multi-Threading and came across a code snippets illustrating the same.

When I tried executing them, the behavior (ie output value) changes as a function of time.

I ran the code in Jupyter Notebook.  [This was from a tutorial in PyCon 2020.](https://github.com/santiagobasulto/pycon-concurrency-tutorial-2020/blob/master/2.%20Thread%20Data%20%26%20Race%20Conditions.ipynb)

**Code Snippet** (I am putting them in separate blocks as an equivalent to me running them in different cells of the notebook):

```
import threading, time, random

COUNTER = 0

def increement(n):
    global COUNTER # Use the global variable declared above
    for _ in range(n):
        COUNTER += 1
        time.sleep(0.001)
    print( f"{threading.current_thread().name} finished counting")

ITERATIONS = 10000 # set number of iterations to increase counter

# create 10 threads each set to run the increement() function 
threads = [threading.Thread(target=increement, args=(ITERATIONS,) ) for _ in range(10) ]
```

```
[t.start() for t in threads]
```

```
assert COUNTER == (len(threads) * ITERATIONS), f"Invalid value for counter: {COUNTER}, expected value: {len(threads) * ITERATIONS} "
```

`COUNTER`'s value for a 5 sec vs 10 sec gap between running the last 2 cells seems to be 100,000 vs 200,000. In the last cell, even the small timegap between running the `print` function vs `assert` statement results in a change in value.

[image: Screenshot for reference]

My guess is that the threads executing the `increment()` take longer than the other threads (executing the notebook cells) to run. But I'd love to hear the community's explanation & perspective (and also any advice for me).

As a follow up question, if I were to execute a similar code inside a script, how do I ensure that the threads fully finish executing before moving on to further process the `COUNTER` variable? I am aware of `threading.Thread.join()` but when I invoked it after starting the thread, all of them executed sequentially (like the below code snippet). What I was wondering is whether there is a way to wait till all the threads finish executing **concurrently** and then process `COUNTER`?

```
# Using join() this way results in all threads getting sequentially executed
for t in threads:
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

(Based on further digging, this is what I found out. Please correct me if I am wrong).

> What I was wondering is whether there is a way to wait till all the threads finish executing concurrently and then process COUNTER?

This can be achieved with following code. By executing `t.join()` in a separate loop, we prevent sequential execution by ensuring that other threads start one after another immediately.

```
[ t.start() for t in threads]
[ t.join() for t in threads]
```

Even with this updation, `COUNTER`'s value will still be equal to `len(threads)*ITERATIONS` because the update operation happens atomically in the above function.

Multi-Threading in Python has certain quirks compared to other languages. Python has something called **Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)** which prevents two or more threads from simultaneously accessing a shared variable/memory.

In the function's code mentioned in question, updation of the variable happens in a single statement (i.e. atomically), thereby preventing other threads from accessing it while one thread is writing to it.

However, if the endgoal is to demonstrate the idea of Race Condition using Python (albeit the existence of GIL), the function code can be modified as follows:

```
def increement(n):
    global COUNTER # Use the global variable declared above
    for _ in range(n):
        x = COUNTER
        COUNTER = x + 1
        time.sleep(0.001)
    print( f"{threading.current_thread().name} finished counting")
```

In this way, `COUNTER` is no longer modified atomically but in 2 separate steps, thereby allowing multiple threads to read out-of-date value of `COUNTER`.

Edit: When the operations `x=COUNTER` and `COUNTER=x+1` are in adjacent lines, though they are technically not atomic, the Scheduler might choose to execute them together as they are consequtive instructions. But if I were to place some other instruction between these 2 statements like a `print(x)`, due to system calls the execution will definitely be no longer atomic and hence higher the chances of code doing "bad" things (read: Data Race condition).

Also, read: [What is a race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition?rq=1)